# How do I fix these missing libraries?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import, libs

[image]

So these are the three missing libraries, that I still didn't manage to add to my imported project. I tried a lot of things and it simply won't work. I downloaded google play services with SDK manager and google-play-services_lib isn't there, while google-play-services is there, but I need both. As for CaptureActivity and PortraitQR, I tried adding both jars from the project dexedLibs but it didn't work. I also tried downloading [this](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/downloads/detail?name=ZXing-2.2.zip) but I don't know how to add it to the project (I only know how to add single jars)

EDIT: Okay so I played around a little bit and I think I'm closer to a solution now. I manually added google play services lib and capture activity and this is how libraries look like now:
[image]

The only remaining problem is that now there is a red exclamation mark next to my project and when I go to build paths there is this red error:

[image]

I tried to look for captureactivity.jar but I can't find it. Can anyoe help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should import them with  new project->Android project from existing code-> then locate your projects path and also make sure you make them library project; right click on project-> properties-> android -> scroll to bottom and check 'is library' checkbox

and the path for google play services lib is => 
\extras\google\google_play_services

you can also find sample code on there

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried adding google play services library project exactly like you said and it went well, but the error still remains. There are still 3 libraries missing.

Comment: is there any green one with tick? if that's the case then you can delete the google play with red cross one. if you can post the image it would be very helpful

Comment: No, none of them is green. After I imported the library project everything stayed the same, not a single thing changed. I did however try to delete the red one and add the new library project manually and then it was green, but that ruined the project (every java and xml file became red). After I added the project library manually like [this](http://shrani.si/f/3j/E8/1TVerzfp/33f34f43f.png) everything in the original project became red.

Comment: I think I'm closer to a solution now, please check my original post edit

Comment: ok delete the capture.jar from android dependincies, by right clicking on it -> build path-> remove from build path so there will remain only one red cross, for that i guess you should try to find the project location then add it

Comment: I can't remove it, I can't even right click it. Nothing happens, also if I select it, there is no remove option available

Comment: no, sadly it still doesn't work, pressing delete does nothing

Comment: your question helped me the most and I've nearly solved my problem so I'll just accept your answer :) but if you get any new idea on how I could delete this, let me know, thank you!

Comment: thanks for the accepting :) you should be able to delete that jar by simply selecting it and hit delete on keyboard :S

Answer (score 1):

These three are library projects. Let's say you have a project in your IDE which is called "PortraitQR". It must be open before your project, Evanturist, can see it as a library project. And it's the same story for the other two library projects. If it doesn't work, try removing them in the dialog you've shown here and adding them again.

You should *not* use any .jar files for this to work. You should have these three projects open in your IDE.